# How to implement default toolbar for material picker for react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui, frontend

I'm trying to customize toolbar for material picker (v3) by adding title inside the dialog.
I was able to do that for the KeyboardDatePicker following this thread. (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/1180)
But I also need to implement it in the KeyboardTimePicker.

I tried to do it by changing the views to hours and minutes but they weren't same as the default toolbar in the KeyboardTimePicker (default toolbar can edit time on top also)

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Please, add your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by below and added additional component on top of the TimePickerToolbar

```
import { T as TimePickerToolbar } from '@material-ui/pickers/esm/TimePickerToolbar-81100fab.js';

<KeyboardTimePicker
        ToolbarComponent={(props) => <TimePickerToolbar {...props}/>
      />
```